# How to map C# ticks to PostgreSQL timestamp when using a Protocol Buffer model with Dapper?

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, protobuf-net, npgsql

I'm using protobuf-net in my application to send logged data from a remote site to the server. There are multiple data types - a sample message of one of these is as follows:

```
message Sample {
    required int64 recording_time = 1; // UTC Timestamp in Ticks
    required double x_position = 2;
    required double y_position = 3;
    required double x_velocity = 4;
    required double y_velocity = 5;
}
```

On the server, the object is stored in a PostgreSQL database. All the `double` fields in the Protocol Buffer (`proto2`) message are mapped to `double` fields in PostgreSQL. The timestamp field, `uint64 recording_time` must be mapped to a `timestamp with time zone` field in the database.

I want to use the same C# class (with `ProtoContract` attribute) to serialize `Sample` on the client, and also with Dapper for database operations (perhaps with an extension, e.g. FastCRUD).

This requires a mapping/conversion between `ticks` (*C# type: long*) and `timestamp with time zone` (*C# type: DateTime*). What is the best way to implement this, without creating a second class?

This is how I currently write objects to database:

```
string sql = "COPY samples (recording_time, x_position, y_position, x_velocity, y_velocity) FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)";
using (var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport(sql))
{
    foreach (Sample sample in sampleList)
    {
        writer.StartRow();

        writer.Write(new DateTime(sample.RecordingTime, DateTimeKind.UTC), NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTZ);

        writer.Write(sample.X_Position, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double);
        writer.Write(sample.Y_Position, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double);
        writer.Write(sample.X_Velocity, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double);
        writer.Write(sample.Y_Velocity, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double);

    }
}
```

This is how I want to write to database:

```
foreach (Sample sample in sampleList)
{
    conn.Insert<Sample>(sample);
}
```

And use the corresponding `Query` method for retrieval.

Comment: But you will use C# code to store value in database still? If yes, you can just construct C# DateTime object from those ticks and use that in your database call.

Comment: @Evk Yes, I'm currently creating a DateTime object and writing to database via Npgsql. However, I would like to use Dapper (or similar ORM) to retrieve a `Sample` object from a query. Is there a way to write this conversion into Dapper configuration/initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use the same C# class (with ProtoContract attribute) to serialize Sample on the client, and also with Dapper for database operations (perhaps with an extension, e.g. FastCRUD).

Personally, I think that's the problem - trying to do two very different things with the same object. However! It isn't necessarily impossible. In particular, note that protobuf-net will happily work with private members. So one option might be:

```
public WhateverYouNeedForTheDatabase Foo { get; set; }

[ProtoMember(someNumber)]
private WhateverYouNeedForTheSerializer FooSerialized {
    get { return FromX(Foo); }
    set { Foo = ToX(value); }
}
```

You *can* do similar with dapper, but it is less convenient. In particular, in your case:

```
public DateTime RecordingTime { get; set; }

[ProtoMember(1)]
private long RecordingTimeSerialized {
    get { return DateTimeToUnixTime(RecordingTime); }
    set { RecordingTime = UnixTimeToDateTime(value); }
}
```

This has no additional storage requirement (no extra fields).

Comment: Thanks @Marc! I didn't know that protobuf-net will work with private members. I'm going to test your recommentation with my setup.

Comment: Thanks! That resolves the issue with one class. My application has 5 models. _Is it possible to avoid writing the repetitious code for each class?_ One option I've tried is to define a `class Timestamp {   public DateTime RecordingTime { get; set; }    
[ProtoMember(1)]    
private long RecordingTimeSerialized {...} }` but I got stuck when mapping a `Timestamp` object's `RecordingTime` property to the corresponding datebase field.

Comment: @Arbi I've had a wish list item to allow DateTime as long in protobuf, but I haven't implemented it to date